# Captcha validation error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I found problem regarding my captcha validation form, for more detail here i show my code :

**Captcha function**

```
private function gbr_captcha()
    {
        $vals = array(
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
        'font_path' => './system/fonts/impact.ttf',
        'img_width' => '150',
        'img_height' => 40
        );
        $cap = create_captcha($vals);
        $datamasuk = array(
            'captcha_time' => $cap['time'],
            'word' => $cap['word']
            );
        $expiration = time()-3600;
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM captcha WHERE captcha_time < ".$expiration);
        $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $datamasuk);
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $cap['image'];
    }
```

**Captcha Validation Form**

```
    if(empty($cek))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $frm['gbr_captcha'] = $this->gbr_captcha();
            $this->load->view("app_admin/login/index",$frm);
        }
        else
        {
            $u = $this->input->post('username');
            $p = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->app_model->getLoginData($u,$p);
        }
    }
```

It's working to show captcha in my web, but to validate captcha inputed from user was correct or not, it's not working, I think my problem come from my validation, if there any advice to fix my code, please share, thanks..

Comment: Hmm, I can not see the part where you asking the database if the captcha is existing.
Check it here : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html

Comment: so, what should i add to my code? can you give me reference

Comment: unclear what you asking. please clear it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing following data into your Database

```
 $datamasuk = array(
            'captcha_time' => $cap['time'],
            'word' => $cap['word']
            );
```

IMHO there is nothing which identifies the user (like the ip address.). You wont be able to get the already generated and stored text to compare. Because you dont have anything which points to the user.

Option 1: Store more information like ip address and when you trying to validate the captcha ask the database if there is any record for the ip address.

Option 2: Store the captcha in a session like

```
$this->session->set_userdata("captcha", ["expires"=> time()+3600, "data" => captcha_string])
```

That way is easier to validate (at least for me).

I hope it was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a callback function in your captcha to validate if it is correct.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'trim|required|callback_checkCaptcha');

function checkCaptcha($word){
$ip = $this->session->get_userdata("ip");
    //check db/query db if the captcha word is correct
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM captcha WHERE word = {$word} and ip={$ip}"
//return true or false if word exists or not
    }
```

And secondly how can you determine that it is the exact captcha?
You can store the user ip address, or set cookies/session